# Cloudinary::PreloadedFile cannot retrieve file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary

I've doing a direct upload to the Cloudinary. I can succesfully upload a file to the Cloudinary, and get it's metadata, but everything after falls.

It's really a shot in the dark, but i have an unsolvable problem on my hand.

```
if params[:image_id].present?
  preloaded = Cloudinary::PreloadedFile.new(params[:image_id])         
  raise "Invalid upload signature" if !preloaded.valid?
  @model.image_id = preloaded.identifier

  if @model.save
    return render :json => @model, :status => :ok
  end
end
```

I've done everything by the book, but this line:

```
preloaded = Cloudinary::PreloadedFile.new(params[:image_id])
```

Throws me an error:

```
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `rindex' for nil:NilClass>
```

I'm in the dark about how to solve it. It doesn't give me any information. What to do?

Comment: rindex() is used to separate the public ID from the file extension, see: https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/blob/master/lib/cloudinary/preloaded_file.rb#L25. Can you make sure that the identifier is being passed properly to that method? Otherwise please share some trace info. Also the code of the uploader itself can be useful.

Comment: I'm doing a signed upload.
I've uploaded a file through `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/*bucket*/auto/upload`, got http://pastebin.com/8kwLeqDn

Comment: What should i pass then to the script? Also, i don't know how to trace the method calls here.

Comment: here's controller code: http://pastebin.com/2c85a4tX

i'm doing an ios application, which queries the server for signatures, then does an image+video upload to the cloudinary, and then should pass the returned file id to the server.

Comment: I've figured it: i should give string like `image/upload/v1479154485/ebqhrfjcuunyhht20xbm.jpg#988cee10bce4c641a89f449bda79a87e0252e7a6` to it. And THEN it's OK. But, Cloudinary does not provide  pastebin.com/8kwLeqDn here this string, I need to monkey-patch it together. Well, OK, that's fine, but it means i still do something wrong.